# Default date range with lightpicker.js and moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How can I get the following [codepen](https://codepen.io/centem/pen/PooLpQr) to default to showing all the data. I currently defaults to 21/11/2019 - 28/11/2019. If I change the range to 01/11/2019 - 30/11/2019 it shows all the data. I'm using lightpicker.js and moment.js. Thank you.

UPDATE: What I'm trying to do is show all the data with nothing in the Date Range. Just page defaulting to show everything with no filters. Then I should be able to filter if I choose dates in the Date Range. When I comment out the line `picker.setDateRange(new Date(), moment().add(7, 'day'));` It show blank text box for the Date Range but no data is shown.

JS

```
var picker = new Lightpick({
        field: document.getElementById('datepickerA'),
        singleDate: false
    });     
    picker.setDateRange(new Date(), moment().add(7, 'day'));
    $scope.onOkA = function(){
      var startDate = picker.getStartDate().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
      var endDate = picker.getEndDate().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
      if(startDate && endDate){
            $scope.filteredTicketA = $scope.ticketsA.filter(ele=>{
            return (new Date(ele.Date)-new Date(startDate)>=0) && (new Date(ele.Date)-new Date(endDate)<=0)
            })
          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` will default to today, if you want it be 01/11/2019 then use `new Date(2019,11-1, 1)`.

However I would use some constants to make code clearer, replace picker.setDateRange() sentence with these 3 lines:

```js
var startDate = new Date(2019,11-1, 1); // be aware that month is 0 based.
var endDate = moment(startDate).endOf('month');
picker.setDateRange(startDate, endDate);
```

as a quick solution for onOKA(){} I would change this:

```js
var defaultStartDate = moment(new Date(1, 10, 2019));
var startDate = (pickerB.getStartDate() || defaultStartDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Edorka. I updated the question to make it a little clearer.

Comment: I see on your fiddle that both tabs are showing all elements. Is it now correct?